# Adjective for "something in which you always find something new"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Or alternatively, "something in which you're always able to find/discover something new".

#### An example:

A book, which you read multiple times, and every time you read it, you

- see a whole new aspect of something, e.g. about the plot,
- notice some detail that you haven't noticed before,
- understand some joke you haven't understood before.

... and other features that make a book more *rereadable*, or *timeless*.

#### Another example:

A computer game, which you play over and over, and you always seem to

- discover new possibilities about what the game allows you to do,
- find new locations in the in-game world that you haven't found before,
- notice some intentionally hidden message or joke, i.e. an [*Easter egg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)).

... and other features that increase [replayability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_value).

Is there a single adjective describing this property?

Comment: A fount of freshness and new ideas.

Comment: Assuming you have a large supply of air, _unfathomable_. (the depth metaphor)

Comment: If you think of each newly discovered aspect of the thing as a different facet of it, then _multifaceted_ makes a pretty good (though modest) adjective for indicating its multitudinous aspects and its limitless capacity to surprise and edify you.

Comment: @SvenYargs _Multifaceted_ is pretty close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe it as having *depth* or being *deep*; or *extensive* (or *extensively replayable*, for a game), if it covers a great range of things, or gives you a lot to do or think about; or perhaps *profound* if it causes you to keep pondering new things.

Answer (score 1):

**"self-renewing"**

renew - (v tr) - to make (something) new, fresh, or strong again, (v intr.) to become new again. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/renew)

- Self renewing people require times of solitude and quiet. [(The Self Renewing Adult)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0yxaAAAAYAAJ&q=self-renewing&dq=self-renewing&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=V7atVPTxPIG2evitgMgH&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAjgK)
- The main outcome of such training is a self-renewing system which could...[(Leaders and Managers)](https://www.google.com.br/search?tbm=bks&hl=pt-BR&q=self-renewing&=#q=self-renewing&hl=pt-BR&tbm=bks&start=30)

Answer (score 1):

"ever-fresh".  Ever-fresh. Ever-fresh? Ever-fresh!

Answer (score 0):

> When things are **dynamic**, [new changes and fresh energy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dynamic) are **always** in the air.

Answer (score 0):

***[Alive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alive?searchDictCode=all)***

> Having interest and meaning:

His history lessons are *alive* with fresh perspective.

Alternately,

[***Avant-garde***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/avant-garde)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Favouring or introducing new and experimental ideas and
>   methods:

Answer (score 0):

> ### Fertile
>
> adjective
>   
> 1.
>   bearing, producing, or capable of producing vegetation, crops, etc., abundantly; prolific:
>   *fertile soil.*
>   
> 2.
>   bearing or capable of bearing offspring.
>   
> 3.
>   abundantly productive:
>   *a fertile imagination.*
>   
> 4.
>   producing an abundance (usually followed by of or in):
>   *a land fertile of wheat.*
>   
> 5.
>   conducive to productiveness:
>   *fertile showers.*
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definition for “fertile”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fertile)</sub>

> ### Prolific
>
> adjective
>   
> 1.
>   producing offspring, young, fruit, etc., abundantly; highly fruitful:
>   *a prolific pear tree.*
>   
> 2.
>   producing in large quantities or with great frequency; highly productive:
>   *a prolific writer.*
>   
> 3.
>   profusely productive or fruitful (often followed by in or of):
>   *a bequest prolific of litigations.*
>   
> 4.
>   characterized by abundant production:
>   *a prolific year for tomatoes.*
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definition for “prolific”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prolific)</sub>

> ### Productive
>
> adjective
>   
> 1.
>   having the power of producing; generative; creative:
>   *a productive effort.*
>   
> 2.
>   producing readily or abundantly; fertile:
>   *a productive vineyard.*
>   
> 3.
>   causing; bringing about (usually followed by of):
>   *conditions productive of crime and sin.*
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definition for “productive”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/productive)</sub>